# query jsonB column for a field value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table dummy with column 'event' which is jsonB. I want to query the rows where the field 'code' has value 'xyz'.

I am running this query on my db

```
select * 
from dummy 
where event::jsonB ->'code' -> 'string'='"xyz"'
```

returns results

but

```
select * 
from dummy 
where event ->> 'code' = 'xyz'
```

doesn't. Can some one please tell me why?

Comment: Without seeing the JSON object you are working on this is not answerable. Add the object to your question as an update.

Comment: you also taged 'java' maybe you need give us more context then we can understand your problem.

Comment: Unrelated, but: if the column is really defined as `jsonb`  then the cast `::jsonb` is useless

Comment: Well, `event -> 'code' -> 'string'` references a completely different element in the JSON document than `event ->> 'code'`